# Angular 2 - Bootstrapping Application with Remote Config File

Tags: angular

I have a dependency on fetching a remote JSON config data prior to any routes.  What is the recommended way to do so?

Is a [guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) the recommended way?

Comment: When you say remote json, you mean you're fetching the json via http?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Thanks for the answer.  That sounds like the preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, guards are for restricting route access to user roles - e.g. guest/customers/admins/etc.

You can use the router.resetConfig() function to change the routes after the initial load.  So, you could load the app with a default empty root, then after you've fetched your json, resetConfig() with the new routes.

For example:

```
        let rc: RouterConfig = [
            { path: 'xyz', component: Test },
            { path: 'abc', component: Test },
        ];
        router.resetConfig(rc);
```